# createChooser() intent exception "requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()"

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, scoped-storage

The app needs to share a PDF file stored in the root of the cacheDir with other apps. The issue is seen on Android 12, possibly other versions too.

Manifest:

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Provider paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <cache-path name="cache" path="." />
</paths>
```

Intent:

```
        val pdfFile = File(requireContext().cacheDir, pdfFileName)
        val fileUri: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            requireContext().applicationContext,
            requireContext().packageName.toString() + ".provider",
            pdfFile
        )
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        intent.type = "application/pdf"
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Document"))
```

The share sheet successfully opens but this exception always shows at that point and subsequently sharing to another app fails.

```
Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading 
androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri
content://uk.co.packagename.provider/cache/8BEDF7212-0DE46-42B0-9FA9-32C434BDD2F3HO.pdf
from pid=15363, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
```

The provider as a whole cannot be exported and the URI permission appears to already be granted. I've read through the Android file sharing docs and many S/O answers but I cannot see what needs correcting, can you?

Comment: That looks OK. Have you tried `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this).setType("application/pdf").addStream(fileUri).startChooser()` ?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you, ShareCompat does not trigger the permission error (yay) ... but the share still subsequently fails (boo), e.g. sharing to Gmail results in: ComposeActivity: Error adding attachment [CONTEXT android_log_tag="ComposeActivity" ] fha: FileNotFoundException when openAssetFileDescriptor.

Comment: Try replacing `requireContext().packageName.toString()` in your authority with `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`. Beyond that, are you *sure* that `pdfFile` exists?

Comment: @CommonsWare Mark, as you suspected the file did not exist, only one with a v similar name. Thank you so much for prompting me to confirm. If you want to add an answer to suggest anyone with this issue may want to double-check the file, I'd be happy to mark it as the answer (for me at least).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the limitations of `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` is that it does not check to see if the file exists. There are legit reasons for getting a `Uri` to a file that does not exist, such as for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Still, it means that just getting the `Uri` is no guarantee that that the `Uri` is useful for reading content.

Compounding that problem is that "does the file exist" via `exists()` feels like it may be a bit dicey, especially for external storage.

So, it's pretty important to make sure that you have the right `File` object, and that it should point to an already-existing file, before you call `getUriForFile()`.

Answer (score 7):

The reason a security exception (*"requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()"*) is thrown is because the android system is trying to access the shared resource to give the user a preview of what would be shared.

The best approach is to use the *[intent.setClipData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setClipData(android.content.ClipData))* to share the resource in addition to `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri)`

The code should look like this:

```
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
intent.setClipData(ClipData.newRawUri("", fileUri))
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```

**@skvalex**'s answer above works, but it is a hacky way of giving the Android system access to the file for preview in the application share picker screen.

For a additional reference on this, please take a look at the [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) class as well.

Answer (score 3):

After checking what package caused this exception it turned out to be `android` system. So after granting uri permission, I see no more exceptions like this in the logs:

```
requireContext().grantUriPermission("android", fileUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Also got the image preview in the share sheet. Surely it's an issue from system side or so.